# How do you change the colour of the FF4 menu button?

Tags: css, firefox

I am looking for a way to change the background colour of the menu button on the FF4 beta and to place it on the tab bar simultaneously.

I have achieved the latter effect using various Stylish user styles and chrome.css modifications, but no matter what I do, the menu button is always that hideous shade of orange.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in a new Stylish style, modifying the colors as you wish:

```
#appmenu-button{
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(58,127,197,1), rgba(47,119,189,1), rgba(0,58,229,1)) !important;
}

#appmenu-button:hover{
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(78,147,229,1), rgba(0,78,213,1)) !important;
}

#appmenu-button:-moz-window-inactive{
background: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
}
```

It worked for me when I tested it just now. The current colors give you a blue Firefox app menu. If you want to have the main color stay around (instead of "disappearing") when the Firefox window is inactive, remove the `#appmenu-button:-moz-window-inactive{`...`}` section.

(Note: I used the link in the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/220767/how-do-you-change-the-colour-of-the-ff4-menu-button/220773#220773) provided by [CGA](https://superuser.com/users/6354/cga) to figure out how to do the first two sections, and added the third section based on my own search.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/921416-share-your-custom-firefoxminefield-4-stylish-scripts/) forum thread.